# What is the relation between execution of qt binary and /proc?

Tags: linux, qt5, egl, virtualfilesystem

I am new to Qt and Linux internals.This is for getting a good idea about qt and its execution on Linux.

I have a Qt5 binary running in Linux on Imx6 based evaluation board.I can run my application by:

```
./my_app -platform eglfs
```

While working with this i accidentally unmounted proc file system

```
sudo umount /proc
```

After that my application give an error when i try to run ,which is given bellow:

```
EGL Error : Could not create the egl surface: error = 0x3003
```

1. Can anyone explain how the Qt/egl is related to proc file system?
2. What is that particular information needed by Qt/egl from /proc?
3. Is there any way to make that information available without mounting /proc?

Sorry if i am asking wrong question, thank you for your time..

**

### Edit:

**
Output of `strace -e open -f ./fast_cluster/fast_cluster -platform eglfs | grep '/proc'` is given in [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Tm9lTt-pH3Oyevw3FGmkYzf4gy2X1jET5OUXdq69JUY/edit)

Comment: Why not just run `strace -e open -f ./program | grep '/proc'` and find out the answer?

Comment: @user1034749 : thank you... tried the above one and it gives [pid   522] open("/proc/522/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory).Seems like Qt is trying to open proc for obtaining binary path.Any idea why?

Comment: I doubt that's causing the problem. Surely there are other entries.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath : Updated question with full log of 'strace' command